# How to avoid problems created with Java saving data as a reference?

Tags: java

So I have an ArrayList called Graph with 8 entries. Entry 1 is a reference to an integer array called 'source', and entries 2-8 are references to an integer array called 'data'. However, all I really wanted to do was save the data within 'source' and 'data', rather than save references to them. Now because of this, changing 'data' ruins 'Graph', and editing the data stored in 'Graph' is cumbersome.

At this point I'd like to be able to pull data out of 'Graph' one at a time in a while/for loop, store it into a integer array called temp, modify temp, and then store it back into 'Graph', but this doesn't work since this eventually means every entry in 'Graph' is just a reference to 'temp' and they'll all eventually have the same value, which of course is wrong.

What's a good way to go about editing the data in Graph, or reconstructing this so I can avoid this problem?

Here's the code. I'm reading in data from a text file that tells me how to build a graph.

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("graph.txt"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while(line.charAt(z)!=' '){
        sizeString=sizeString+line.charAt(z);
        z++;
    }
     size = Integer.valueOf(sizeString);
     int graph[][] = new int[size][size];

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append("\n");
        line = br.readLine();
        z=0;
        if(line != null){
            while(line.charAt(z)!=' '){
                xString=xString+line.charAt(z);
                z++;
            }
            z++;
            while(line.charAt(z)!=' '){
                yString=yString+line.charAt(z);
                z++;
            }
            z++;
            while(z<line.length()){
                weightString=weightString+line.charAt(z);
                z++;
            }
            System.out.println(xString+yString+weightString);
            x=Integer.valueOf(xString);
            y=Integer.valueOf(yString);
            weight=Integer.valueOf(weightString);

            graph[x][y]=weight;
            xString="";yString="";weightString="";
            vertices++;     
        }
    }

    //Set non adjacent node weights to infinity
    ArrayList Graph = new ArrayList();
    int[] source = new int[2];
    int[] data = new int[2];

    source[0]=0;
    source[1]=-1;

    Graph.add(0,source);

    data[0]=99999;      //Represents 'infinity'
    data[1]=-1;         //No source node
    x=1;

    while(x<graph.length){
        Graph.add(x, data);
        x++;
    }
```

Comment: Some code would be very helpful here

Comment: Look at System.arraycopy and several functions in java.util.Arrays.

Comment: Also... you should post some code.  That will make it easier to help.

Comment: @jahroy -- Not clear to me how changing from an array to an ArrayList would change the reference thing.  You can dynamically change the elements in either, and the change will be immediately reflected.

Comment: Hoser, I suspect your problem is not with "references", but with the concept of "objects" -- references are only a manifestation of objects.  You need to get your head around objects.

Comment: @HotLicks Could you explain a little more what you mean by that? And how could I apply that in this situation?

Comment: Well, looking at your code I suspect your problem is somewhat simpler.  A multi-dimension array, in Java, is an array of arrays, which means that if you copy from `graph[x]` to `temp[x]`, you're copying a reference to the subarray that contains all the `y` elements, rather than copying the individual elements.  To copy the `y` elements you must do so individually (in a loop) or use System.arraycopy or some such.

Comment: @HotLicks Won't I just end up with the same problem in the end though? Say I have a loop rotating through graph, and each iteration copies over one element into temp. In the for loop, I edit temp, and store temp back into graph. Doesn't this again just save a reference to temp? Then this means every iteration through for loop where temp gets edited, every previously saved instance of temp into graph will be dynamically changed.

Comment: Your `graph` array is an array of `int`, which means that the elements are *not* references -- only variables and array elements that reference objects are references.

Comment: By the way, if you used the parameterized type of `ArrayList` (instead of the raw type), you wouldn't have to cast on `Graph.get`

Comment: (You're not making it clear how you copy data to `temp` and back to `graph`, and whether you do it piecemeal or all at once.)

Comment: To clarify what Hot Licks is saying, primitive values (such as int) are not Objects and thus are not by-reference.  On top of that, they are immutable.  Arrays are Objects, and so they are by-reference.

Comment: This is stupid variable naming on my part I guess. I meant to be talking about the ArrayList 'Graph', not the int array 'graph'. Graph is filled with integer arrays, I will be removing them one at a time, storing them into temp (an integer array), editing temp, and then storing them back into Graph. This means Graph is now full of references to temp, so it will be full of integer arrays with the exact same data in all of them, which is not something I want.

Comment: I want to save the data in temp into Graph, not a reference to temp.

Comment: So, are you trying to simply operate on each of the elements in Graph? Why would you want to remove and then re-add them, instead of just looping through and operating on each of them in place?

Comment: @ach Is there a good way to do this with an ArrayList? If so I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @ach -- It's meaningless to say that primitive values are "immutable".  Values are values, and clearly the value 6 cannot change, but a variable that contains a primitive value definitely is NOT immutable (unless declared final).

Comment: You do not have to "remove" an object from, eg, an ArrayList to operate on it.  You just need to obtain a reference for the object.

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah you're right, I have no idea what I was meaning to type when I said they were immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to attempt to provide an answer based on your responses to the comments.  I don't see any variable named 'temp' in your sample code, so I assume you haven't tried to write that part yet.

```
List<int[]> Graph = new ArrayList<int[]>(8); //specify the capacity if it is fixed
//Your existing code that populates Graph here...
for (int[] temp : Graph) {
    //Do some operations on temp...
}
```

or if you only want to operate on elements 1..n of Graph:

```
for (int ii = 1; ii < Graph.size(); ii++) {
    int[] temp = Graph.get(ii);
    //Do some operations on temp...
}
```

Also, when you're populating Graph you'd want to make a copy of the array and then store that, if you don't want to save the reference:

```
int[] srcCopy = new int[source.length];
System.arraycopy(source, 0, srcCopy, 0, source.length);
```

I would also suggest that you use a different variable name instead of 'Graph'. Capitalized identifiers should only be used for Class/Interface variables.

Comment: This seems to result in the exact same problem. Whenever I do temp=Graph.get(ii) it copies over the reference that existed there whenever it was set to match the integer array 'source', now temp is the new reference object to all the elements in Graph and editing it dynamically changes everything in Graph.